# 2D QCD Phase Transitions of Free Energy Gross & Taylor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, phase-transition, yang-mills

Hi I'm currently working on the paper ["Counting Strings and Phase Transitions in 2D QCD"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9404175v2) by W. Taylor, for the most part the paper is quite easy to understand however I cannot see how he manages to write the free energy as a polynomial of A page 16. Basically I'm unsure how he comes up with equation (4.18) and then how he calculates their expansions (4.19). Any help would be much appreciated cheers!

Comment: Do you think you could be helpful to those on mobile and actually copy the relevant equations, rather than forcing us to download a paper and read it on a 4" screen?